# Redundant OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, redundancy

I'm trying to set up a fully redundant OpenVPN tunnel, with two routers on each side.

All the tutorials I saw (such as http://dev.vyatta4people.org/highly-available-openvpn-connection-between-two-offices/) mention a `site-to-site` setting, which doesn't seem to work with OpenVPN on a Linux server (which seems to always require a server and a client).

How can I achieve a similar setup using Linux servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it doesn't immediately answer your question, but I'd go for ipsec for site-to-site VPNs.  I've been running it between Linux endpoints in production for over a decade, and it's *never* let me down.

In my experience, it deals much better with temporary failures in the sites' internet connections, lacking as it does any view of one end being a server and the other end being the one to bring the connection up and down; instead, both ends are peers, and either can initiate, terminate, and re-key connections as it sees fit.

It also deals much better with the geometry issue when you add a third site.

Answer (score 0):

That option is a configuration option, that the vyatta distribution added. It seems to correspond directly to p2p mode in OpenVPN native configuration language.

Just use the following in your OpenVPN configuration file:

```
mode p2p
```